# Token Refresh to Azure KeyVault Access

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I'm getting the following error when I attempt to access a Key Vault from my local machine via

```
DefaultAzureCredential()
```

I'm running the following two lines, but I keep getting an error.

```
client = SecretClient(vault_url=<URL>, credential=DefaultAzureCredential())
secret = client.get_secret(<SECRET NAME>).value
```

```
azure.core.exceptions.ClientAuthenticationError: DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
Attempted credentials:
EnvironmentCredential: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
ManagedIdentityCredential: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no managed identity endpoint found.
SharedTokenCacheCredential: SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. No accounts were found in the cache.
VisualStudioCodeCredential: Azure Active Directory error '(invalid_grant) AADSTS700082: The refresh token has expired due to inactivity. The token was issued on 2020-06-07T03:58:48.4708462Z and was inactive for 90.00:00:00.
```

I've tried logging into Azure via
`az login`
but this doesn't refresh the credential.

Edit:
I've tried a few other configurations found in the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/azure-identity/). What seems strange is the Azure CLI credentials work, since it looks like that's one of the scenarios that is handled by the default credentials.

Comment: Have you tried to use [`AzureCliCredential()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.azureclicredential?view=azure-python) instead of `DefaultAzureCredential()`?

Comment: Thanks, @PamelaPeng - That work. Any idea why that the CLI Credential works when the Default one doesn't? Per the [documentation](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-identity/1.4.0/azure.identity.html#azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredential) it looks like the CLI is one of the cases that Default considers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use `az login` to access Key Vault, both `AzureCliCredential()` and `DefaultAzureCredential()` will work well in theory. But the error shows at VisualStudioCodeCredential() in your issue.

**VisualStudioCodeCredential:** If a user has signed in to the Visual Studio Code Azure Account extension, DefaultAzureCredential will authenticate as that user.

`DefaultAzureCredential` attempts to authenticate via the following mechanisms in this order, stopping when one succeeds:

[image]

So, you need to use `AzureCliCredential()` or set `exclude_visual_studio_code_credential=true` to make sure skip VisualStudioCode.

For more details about Azure Identity, see [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/identity/azure-identity).

Comment: My problem was similar, and the solution was to specify `exclude_shared_token_cache_credential=True` to force the application to use VisualStudioCodeCredential. Great.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be working with DefaultAzureCredential(), you need the following:-

- Service principal
- Give access to service principal in KeyVault access policy.

When you have done the above, you need to setup the following environment variables:-

- AZURE_CLIENT_ID  (this is clientID of the above service principal(sp))
- AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET  (this is client secret key of above sp)
- AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID  (this is the subscription id in Azure.)
- AZURE_TENANT_ID (this is Active directory ID)

To see all environment variables on windows, open command prompt type command "set" and press enter.

To set a environment variable on windows, for example you want to set up **AZURE_CLIENT_ID** variable with value **jbfdshfbsdfbdsbdgbdjgbdfjbdfj** , open command prompt type command "setx AZURE_CLIENT_ID jbfdshfbsdfbdsbdgbdjgbdfjbdfj" and press enter

it will not show the updated until you restart the command prompt.

Then restart the visual studio/ vs code where you are using DefaultAzureCredentials()

Answer (score 0):

This is late, but perhaps it could help someone else avoid spending hours trying to figure this out.  I work primarily in Java using Intellij, I kept getting the following error no matter what I did.  I was logged in, via web, cli, intellij plugin, cleared identity cache, you name it.

```
com.azure.core.exception.ClientAuthenticationException: DefaultAzureCredential authentication failed. ---> VisualStudioCodeCredential authentication failed. Error Details: AADSTS50173: The provided grant has expired due to it being revoked, a fresh auth token is needed. The user might have changed or reset their password. The grant was issued on '2021-10-15T12:45:38.0655988Z' and the TokensValidFrom date (before which tokens are not valid) for this user is '2021-11-29T19:36:56.0000000Z'.
```

While I did not 'solve' the issue, my work-around was just openning VS Code and signing in with the Azure Account plugin.  Then I had no issue in Intellij.  Note that VSCode had no project or code loaded in it either.

Answer (score 0):

I received a similar error when attempting to connect to a Key Vault from an Azure Linux jump box.  It had been over 90 days since I had last accessed the vault from this box.  It turns out that I needed to do a new az login request to refresh my token though the error itself didn't specifically indicate this.